# Again, "if it wasn't" or "if it weren't"?

Tags: conditionals, subjunctive-mood

I have read a lot of information about this topic, but I still don't know why my book says that the answer is "wasn't" in the following sentence:

If the driving test ___________ so difficult, there would be more accidents.

If this is a hypothetical case (the fact is the test is difficult, not easy), why does my book say the answer is "wasn't" and not "weren't"?

Comment: It should be *weren't*. The majority of English speakers hardly ever use the mood formerly known as the past subjunctive, so *wasn't* is perfectly fine to use, probably even in the most formal writing.

Comment: If _wasn't_ is 'perfectly fine' here, as Huddleston, Pullum et al agree, and as has been stated before on ELU, you may be wondering why '[i]t should be _weren't_'. I am. Any book insisting on one or the other is over-prescriptive.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["if it wasn't for..." vs "if it weren't for"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73134/if-it-wasnt-for-vs-if-it-werent-for)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use "If I was" vs. "If I were"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/660/when-to-use-if-i-was-vs-if-i-were)

Comment: Your book is wrong to reject either. I always use *were* for the subjunctive. As did many of the people I grew up with and went to school with. However, *was* is more common. But both are acceptable.